# Creating subset in temporal database in PostgreSQL based on time and date

Tags: postgresql, date, time, subset

I have a temporal database and I wanted to create a subset based on a specific time and date. For example I want to have a subset from 2007-09-29 00:05 to 2007-09-29 01:30.

Sample Table s_2:

```
       temp    DateeTIMEE
1     -1.64 2007-09-29 00:01:09
2     -1.76 2007-09-29 00:03:09
3     -1.83 2007-09-29 00:05:09
4     -1.86 2007-09-29 00:07:09
5     -1.94 2007-09-29 00:09:09
6     -1.87 2007-09-29 00:11:09
7     -1.87 2007-09-29 00:13:09
8     -1.80 2007-09-29 00:15:09
9     -1.64 2007-09-29 00:17:09
10    -1.60 2007-09-29 00:19:09
11    -1.90 2007-09-29 00:21:09
12    -2.08 2007-09-29 00:23:09
13    -1.94 2007-09-29 00:25:09
14    -2.12 2007-09-29 00:27:09
15    -1.87 2007-09-29 00:29:09
16    -2.18 2007-09-29 00:31:09
17    -1.98 2007-09-29 00:33:09
18    -1.73 2007-09-29 00:35:09
19    -1.84 2007-09-29 00:37:09
20    -2.04 2007-09-29 00:39:09
21    -1.86 2007-09-29 00:41:09
22    -1.94 2007-09-29 00:43:09
23    -1.77 2007-09-29 00:45:09
24    -1.78 2007-09-29 00:47:09
25    -1.50 2007-09-29 00:49:09
26    -1.46 2007-09-29 00:51:09
27    -1.72 2007-09-29 00:53:09
28    -1.67 2007-09-29 00:55:09
29    -1.56 2007-09-29 00:57:09
30    -1.69 2007-09-29 00:59:09
31    -1.97 2007-09-29 01:01:09
32    -1.79 2007-09-29 01:03:09
33    -1.79 2007-09-29 01:05:09
34    -1.84 2007-09-29 01:07:09
35    -1.91 2007-09-29 01:09:09
36    -1.87 2007-09-29 01:11:09
37    -1.98 2007-09-29 01:13:09
38    -1.83 2007-09-29 01:15:09
39    -1.88 2007-09-29 01:17:09
40    -1.88 2007-09-29 01:19:09
41    -1.78 2007-09-29 01:21:09
42    -1.78 2007-09-29 01:23:09
43    -1.66 2007-09-29 01:25:09
44    -1.70 2007-09-29 01:27:09
45    -1.46 2007-09-29 01:29:09
46    -1.36 2007-09-29 01:31:09
47    -1.40 2007-09-29 01:33:09
48    -1.34 2007-09-29 01:35:09
49    -1.34 2007-09-29 01:37:09
50    -1.30 2007-09-29 01:39:09
51    -1.36 2007-09-29 01:41:09
52    -1.40 2007-09-29 01:43:09
53    -1.43 2007-09-29 01:45:09
54    -1.38 2007-09-29 01:47:09
55    -1.40 2007-09-29 01:49:09
56    -1.42 2007-09-29 01:51:09
57    -1.47 2007-09-29 01:53:09
58    -1.66 2007-09-29 01:55:09
59    -1.84 2007-09-29 01:57:09
60    -1.92 2007-09-29 01:59:09
61    -1.88 2007-09-29 02:01:09
62    -2.11 2007-09-29 02:03:09
63    -1.91 2007-09-29 02:05:09
64    -2.04 2007-09-29 02:07:09
65    -1.94 2007-09-29 02:09:09
66    -1.92 2007-09-29 02:11:09
67    -1.80 2007-09-29 02:13:09
68    -1.74 2007-09-29 02:15:09
69    -1.74 2007-09-29 02:17:09
70    -1.76 2007-09-29 02:19:09
71    -1.74 2007-09-29 02:21:09
72    -1.80 2007-09-29 02:23:09
73    -1.80 2007-09-29 02:25:09
74    -1.80 2007-09-29 02:27:09
75    -1.82 2007-09-29 02:29:09
76    -1.90 2007-09-29 02:31:09
77    -1.93 2007-09-29 02:33:09
78    -2.06 2007-09-29 02:35:09
79    -2.08 2007-09-29 02:37:09
80    -1.95 2007-09-29 02:39:09
81    -1.98 2007-09-29 02:41:09
82    -2.32 2007-09-29 02:43:09
83    -1.86 2007-09-29 02:45:09
84    -1.97 2007-09-29 02:47:09
85    -1.64 2007-09-29 02:49:09
86    -2.00 2007-09-29 02:51:09
87    -1.48 2007-09-29 02:53:09
88    -1.74 2007-09-29 02:55:09
89    -1.85 2007-09-29 02:57:09
90    -1.82 2007-09-29 02:59:09
91    -1.82 2007-09-29 03:01:09
92    -1.92 2007-09-29 03:03:09
93    -1.80 2007-09-29 03:05:09
94    -1.54 2007-09-29 03:07:09
95    -1.36 2007-09-29 03:09:09
96    -1.50 2007-09-29 03:11:09
97    -1.59 2007-09-29 03:13:09
98    -1.60 2007-09-29 03:15:09
99    -1.58 2007-09-29 03:17:09
100   -1.81 2007-09-29 03:19:09
101   -2.16 2007-09-29 03:21:09
102   -1.97 2007-09-29 03:23:09
103   -1.94 2007-09-29 03:25:09
104   -2.29 2007-09-29 03:27:09
105   -2.46 2007-09-29 03:29:09
106   -2.42 2007-09-29 03:31:09
107   -2.34 2007-09-29 03:33:09
108   -2.38 2007-09-29 03:35:09
109   -2.44 2007-09-29 03:37:09
110   -2.28 2007-09-29 03:39:09
111   -2.24 2007-09-29 03:41:09
112   -2.26 2007-09-29 03:43:09
```

Expected Results, new subset:

```
  3     -1.83 2007-09-29 00:05:09
    4     -1.86 2007-09-29 00:07:09
    5     -1.94 2007-09-29 00:09:09
    6     -1.87 2007-09-29 00:11:09
    7     -1.87 2007-09-29 00:13:09
    8     -1.80 2007-09-29 00:15:09
    9     -1.64 2007-09-29 00:17:09
    10    -1.60 2007-09-29 00:19:09
    11    -1.90 2007-09-29 00:21:09
    12    -2.08 2007-09-29 00:23:09
    13    -1.94 2007-09-29 00:25:09
    14    -2.12 2007-09-29 00:27:09
    15    -1.87 2007-09-29 00:29:09
    16    -2.18 2007-09-29 00:31:09
    17    -1.98 2007-09-29 00:33:09
    18    -1.73 2007-09-29 00:35:09
    19    -1.84 2007-09-29 00:37:09
    20    -2.04 2007-09-29 00:39:09
    21    -1.86 2007-09-29 00:41:09
    22    -1.94 2007-09-29 00:43:09
    23    -1.77 2007-09-29 00:45:09
    24    -1.78 2007-09-29 00:47:09
    25    -1.50 2007-09-29 00:49:09
    26    -1.46 2007-09-29 00:51:09
    27    -1.72 2007-09-29 00:53:09
    28    -1.67 2007-09-29 00:55:09
    29    -1.56 2007-09-29 00:57:09
    30    -1.69 2007-09-29 00:59:09
    31    -1.97 2007-09-29 01:01:09
    32    -1.79 2007-09-29 01:03:09
    33    -1.79 2007-09-29 01:05:09
    34    -1.84 2007-09-29 01:07:09
    35    -1.91 2007-09-29 01:09:09
    36    -1.87 2007-09-29 01:11:09
    37    -1.98 2007-09-29 01:13:09
    38    -1.83 2007-09-29 01:15:09
    39    -1.88 2007-09-29 01:17:09
    40    -1.88 2007-09-29 01:19:09
    41    -1.78 2007-09-29 01:21:09
    42    -1.78 2007-09-29 01:23:09
    43    -1.66 2007-09-29 01:25:09
    44    -1.70 2007-09-29 01:27:09
    45    -1.46 2007-09-29 01:29:09
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear. Are you just asking about the `BETWEEN` operator to select a range by date? Do you want to weed out ever 2nd/3rd/whatever value? Average within time periods? Please show expected results and more explanation. Comment when you've updated.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Yes I wanted to just "BETWEEN operator to select a range by date and time".

Comment: @CraigRinger, The question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic SQL; I strongly recommend that you have a look at the PostgreSQL manual, in particular the [date/time functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) section and the [PostgreSQL tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html).

The basic usage you want is:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE "DateeTIMEE" BETWEEN '2007-09-29 00:05:09' AND '2007-09-29 01:29:09';
```

Alternately, just use:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE "DateeTIMEE" >= '2007-09-29 00:05:09' AND "DateTIMEE" <= '2007-09-29 01:29:09';
```

Note that I've double-quoted `"DateTIMEE"`. This is because PostgreSQL downcases identifiers unless they're quoted, and you seem to have defined it with mixed case. If Pg complains that the column doesn't exist, maybe you defined it without double-quotes and it got downcased. Try without the double quotes if you have issues.